# Convergence of $x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \alpha(Ax_{n} - b).$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

For an assignment, I need to construct a restriction for $\alpha$ so that $$x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \alpha(Ax_{n} - b)$$ converges towards the solution to $Ax = b$ (Richardson iteration). We know that $A$ is diagonalizable and that its eigenvalues are strictly positive.

I'm having difficulty constructing such a restriction on $\alpha$. All I can think of is that $\alpha \not = 0$, which is quite logical. Beside that I don't really know in what direction I should be looking for an answer. Does anyone maybe have a hint to nudge me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!!

Comment: the usual way of all matrix splitting methods is to consider:
$$x_{n+1}-x^* = (I-\alpha A)(x_n-x^*)=\dots (I-\alpha A)^{n+1}(x_0-x^*),$$
where $x^*$ is the fixed point you are trying to converge to i.e., the solution. From this, you get a sufficient condition will be $||I-\alpha A||_2<1.$ Proving the necessary part involves more work IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by noticing that you are dealing with an arithmetico-geometric sequence (with vectors) which is expressed as : $x_{n+1}=(I-\alpha A)x_n+\alpha b$. There is then a classic way of dealing with those by defining a new sequence $y_n=x_n-c$ where c is well chosen constant such that $(y_n)_n$ follows a geometric progression of common ratio $(I-\alpha A)$ (that is $y_{n+1}=(I-\alpha A)y_n$). The condition for the solution to converge towards $Ax=b$ will be more explicit when expressed with $y_n$ and will lead you to studying the convergence of $(I-\alpha A)^n$ where the diagonalizability of $A$ will be helpful. If you need more help do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, $\alpha \ne 0$ is a necessary condition. Additionally, since you iteration can be written in the form $x_{n+1} = (I- \alpha A) x_n + \alpha b$, a sufficient condition is given by $\|I -\alpha A\| < 1$, for some norm. A necessary and sufficient condition would be that $\rho((I-\alpha A)(I-\alpha A^T))<1$.